# FireFox - None of the "sha384" hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource (Content Security Policy - CSP issue)

Tags: javascript, hash, sha, content-security-policy

This seems to be a very old issue affecting Firefox.

The **SHA384** generated for the javascript ***example.js*** is working fine with Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge (Chromium based), and Opera, but it does not work with the latest Firefox release (ver. 112.02)

As expected, in the console I see the following error:

***None of the "sha384" hashes in the integrity attribute match the content of the subresource***

I have read the following posts on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50523151/firefox-none-of-the-sha256-hashes-in-the-integrity-attribute-match-the-conte) and on [github](https://github.com/cdnjs/cdnjs/issues/12792) already, but it looks like Mozilla did not provide any fix so far. This would limit the adoption of Firefox for websites and applications supporting security features such as the Content Security Policy Level 2, and soon also Level 3.

In principle, it should be an easy fix, expecially for Mozilla's developers.

Does anybody know any workaround for this?